# What is the significance of the star next to your name in the squad list?

Tags: battlefield-3

What is the significance of the star next your name on the squad list in Battlefield 3?

Comment: based on previous bf games i would assume that this is a squad leader ... but i cant confirm this (hence the comment not answer)

Comment: @CraigPilgrim - OK, but is there anything significant to being a squad leader.  When a squad leader get's spotted, they become VERY visible so I hope there is an upside to it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does indeed mean that you are the Squad Leader. As Squad Leader, you have the functionality (or obligation if you prefer) to assign squad tasks. This basically amount to attack/defend a certain point (you get bonus points if your squad then complies).

If you are squad leader, you can set an objective by pressing the "spot" command while targetting the objective.

Also certain servers only allow people to spawn on a squad leader, but a squad leader can spawn on any other squadmate.

Comment: How do you do this (give orders to your squad)?

Comment: @SSumner I edited the answer to include that information

Comment: Edited to add squad leaders get special spawning rules on some servers.

Comment: It appears that if the squad leader is a high enough level, he can [share a perk](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35346/what-does-the-icon-next-to-your-squad-leaders-name-mean) with the rest of the squad members as well.