# What's the point of being squad leader?

Tags: battlefield-3

Sometimes I'll notice in a game that I'm the squad leader. What advantages do I get from being squad leader though? I've never seen a way to mark objectives or anything like that

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the significance of the star next to your name in the squad list?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33631/what-is-the-significance-of-the-star-next-to-your-name-in-the-squad-list)

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/33631/5628 The link to the "significance of the star" question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the squad leader, you can set objectives by sighting in a target and pressing the 'back' button (left of the guide button). (You receive additional points when those orders are executed.)
The easiest example would be in a game of Conquest. Point yourself at a capture point on hit the Select button. (Xbox) You can also set WayPoints, and at some point the Squad Leader can call in artillery strikes. I'm sure there are additional commands, and other methods based on the platform that you are playing on.

Comment: Some servers only allow squadmates to spawn on the squad leader, but the squad leader can spawn on anyone else

Comment: @SSumner in hardcore mode you can only spawn on the squad leader, although this is also a standalone server setting that can be toggled on or off -- you're most likely to see it working on a hardcore server.

Comment: This answer only partially answers the question - I think OP wants to know *how* to '...mark objectives or anything like that'. And without even a meaningful manual, I'm as equally mystified myself.