# What does the icon next to your squad leader's name mean?

Tags: battlefield-3

Most of the times (always?) there is an icon next to the squad leader's name (see picture below). I'm not talking about the class icon which is visible for all squad members, but rather the icon between the class icon and the name. Sometimes this is a star but I've also seen it be what looks like an ammo clip as well as a bomb blast or something.

It *seems* to indicate some sort of upgrade the user has attached but I'm not sure I'm correct. An also, what is the reasoning behind:

- What upgrade is shown - you typically have multiple upgrade/perks available at any given time
- Why only for the squad leader? Isn't it just as interesting to see this information for all members of the squad?

[image: Battefield 3 HUD]

(note: I found this image online, it looks slightly different on my ps3)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the significance of the star next to your name in the squad list?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33631/what-is-the-significance-of-the-star-next-to-your-name-in-the-squad-list)

Comment: I saw that question but I am also asking about the other icons that can be there instead of the star

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it is a star, then it means that they are the squad leader. If it is an ammo clip or something like that, then that means that this person has a squad perk equipped. [image]

So, in order on the above picture, we have:

- Squad Sprint
- Squad Flak
- Squad Explosives
- Squad Cover
- Squad Suppression
- Squad Frags
- Squad Ammo

Comment: Aha, thanks.. Could you elaborate on what those squad perks are and I'll be happy to accept this answer.

Comment: See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52248/what-are-squad-perks) for further info on squad perks