# What are "Squad Perks?"

Tags: battlefield-3

The answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35346/what-does-the-icon-next-to-your-squad-leaders-name-mean) stated that there are *"squad perks"* that affect your entire squad, but left a lot of questions unanswered:

- What do each of these perks do? *(I haven't unlocked all the individual perks yet)*
- At what levels do these perks unlock?
- Do these stack with the individual perks?
- Do you *have* to be squad leader for your squad-mates to get the perk?  What if a member of the squad has a squad-perk but the squad-leader doesn't?
- How effective are the squad-perks compared to the individual-perks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Squad perks are perks that span across all of the members in a squad.

1. Squad SPRINT(Rank 23) - Makes you and your squad run faster. (+10%)

   Squad AMMO(Rank 26) - Lets you and your squad hold more ammo clips. (2x's as much)

   Squad FLAK (Rank 29) - Gives you and your squad more armor from explosive damage. (-10%)

   Squad EXPL (Rank 31) - Gives you and your squad more rocket ammo, C4, and mines. (2x's as much)

   Squad SUPR ( Rank 33) - Makes you and your squads bullets have more of a suppressive effect. (+50%)

   Squad COVR (Rank 35) - Makes you an your squad more immune to suppressive fire. (-33%)

   Squad FRAG (Rank 37) - Gives you and your squad more grenades. (1)
2. No they do not stack with individual perks, plan your squad accordingly.
3. No you do not have to be a squad leader for the perks to work for the squad. The leader does not have to have a squad perk if he doesn't want to, it doesn't matter.
4. The squad perks are **very** effective, they are essentially the individual perks but span across your whole squad. Once you have them you can no longer access the regular version of the perk.

Courtesy of @CruelCow [this](http://symthic.com/?s=bf3&sb=spec) link gives you some insight as to percentages of benefits and how they scale.

Comment: You beat me to it!!! well played though. +1

Comment: For **4**, I was hoping for actual percentages.  Do the squad- and individual-perks have exactly the same effect?  Or is one more effective than the other?  Also, do you have any links to back up **2** and **3**, other than personal experience?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft http://symthic.com/?s=bf3&sb=spec has the percentages. They don't stack, the loading screen says so, and it is easy to test with EXPL/AMMO/FRAG.

Comment: Once you have the squad perks there is no reason to return to the normal ones. The squad ones are equal or better always. Very nice link @CruelCow , I couldn't find those numbers for the life of me.

Comment: Woth noting: Squad EXPL gives extra C4 and AT mines as well.

Comment: I like my extra C4. Some much explosive goodness

Comment: Also, once you unlock the squad perk, the individual perk is no longer accessible. So if you unlock squad Sprint, you can no longer access just personal sprint.